# Customize single coordinate in d3.layout.tree()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to customize the d3.layout.tree by setting manually one of the two coordinates. The different branches of my tree have time stamps and thus for a smoother representation it would be nice to correlate one coordinate to time.

Does someone know if one can tune the tree layout to accept fixed coordinates? Or, if not, maybe an alternative approach?

I have tried to work around it by the use of d3.layout.force which allows to fix the positions of single nodes. However, I could not find how to fix just one coordinate and leave the other to be determined by the force algorithm.

To illustrate, the tree should look very much like this: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html 
(unfortunately it looks exactly like this) but with the x-coords explicitly set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in case someone is interested, here is my workaround using d3.force.layout. It is not perfect but does the job for what I need it for.

Basically I assign the proberty `born` of each node to its x-coord, thus restraining the force layout to only work on the y-coord.

If you have any improvements, please let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.geom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.layout.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

circle.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var w = 2960,
    h = 2000,
    node,
    link,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .distance(200)
    .charge(-10)
    .gravity(0)
    .size([w, h]);

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

d3.json("collapsable/relations.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  update();
});

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

function tick(e) {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.born; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.born; });
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.born; });
}
      // Update the links…
  link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes…
  node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill", color);


  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .style("stroke", function(d) {return d.gender == "m" ? "steelblue" : "red";})
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  force.on("tick",tick)

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();
}

function tick(e) {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}


// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```